# Find Current Time in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How can I find the current time and it's region if i have current location, latitude and longitude?

I can get any city of any country as current location and  having latitude and longitude of it and have to get current time and region of it.  Then how to find current time and region based on that.

Answer (score 2):

You will need a service such as [Geonames timesezone](http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html#timezone) and then adjust the `NSDate` to that timezone offset. The method `dateWithCalendarFormat:timeZone:` can be used with the date returned from `[NSDate date]`.

[NSDate Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

**Edit:**

That webservice provides timezone offsets. dstOffset would be best in most situations since it accounts for daylight savings time otherwise use gmtOffset. [`NSTimeZone`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/Reference/Reference.html) object can be created by using the static method `+ (id)timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:(NSInteger)seconds` and converting the offset from hours to seconds.

Answer (score 0):

`[NSDate date]` will return a `NSDate` object with the current date and time.

Comment: If i have choose any city of any country ,and if that is the current location then how to find it's current time.

Comment: For Example I get from my database that my current location is Pune then how to find pune's curretn time.Pune is for example it may be any city of any country in this world.

Comment: You will probably need a webservice to convert the lat/lon to a region and get the time zone. Check out my post and see if that helps.

Comment: Now always. This command does not considers the daylight saving. C'mon Apple!